# Pandas: attribute_error when converting timestamps to EST

Tags: python, pandas

Consider this simple example

```
idx2=[pd.to_datetime('2016-08-31 22:08:12') , 
     pd.to_datetime('2016-08-31 22:08:12'),
     pd.to_datetime(np.NaN)]

test2=pd.DataFrame({'value':[1,1,3], 'groups' : ['A',np.NaN,'A']},index=idx2)
test2.reset_index(inplace = True)


test2
Out[29]: 
                index groups  value
0 2016-08-31 22:08:12      A      1
1 2016-08-31 22:08:12    NaN      1
2                 NaT      A      3
```

I would like to convert the column `index` to EST, but this

```
test2['index'].map(lambda x: x.tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern').tz_localize(None))
```

gives me

`AttributeError: 'NaTType' object has no attribute 'tz_localize'`

Using `x[x.notnull()]` does not work either. what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use `reset_index`, instead just operate directly on the `DatetimeIndex` which has `tz_localize` and `tz_convert` built-in:

```
test2.index = test2.index.tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern').tz_localize(None)
```

The resulting output:

```
                    groups  value
2016-08-31 18:08:12      A      1
2016-08-31 18:08:12    NaN      1
NaT                      A      3
```

As noted by @DSM, you can use the `.dt` accessor if you want to do this on a column, but you'll need to use 3 instances of `.dt`, one before each timezone operation:

```
test2.reset_index(inplace=True)
test2['index'] = test2['index'].dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern').dt.tz_localize(None)

                index groups  value
0 2016-08-31 18:08:12      A      1
1 2016-08-31 18:08:12    NaN      1
2                 NaT      A      3
```

Comment: Even if the OP does use `reset_index`, he could use `.dt` to get at the methods.

Comment: thanks but i need to do that on a column, not the index. also this works fine without naT...

Comment: crazy stuff! Thanks. any idea why this works without the dt accessor when there a no missing values?

Comment: Under the hood pandas uses a different object for `NaT` than regular `Timestamps`  (see `df['index'].map(type)`).  I'm guessing that when you use `tz_localize`/`tz_convert` on an entire column/index there's some filtering done ignore the `NaTType` objects.  Based on your error, it appears that the pandas developers haven't implemented `tz_localize`/`tz_convert` for `NaTType`, and when you use `map` you're directly hitting the `NaTType`, as opposed to it getting ignored beforehand.  It seems both should return `NaT` when given `NaT` as input, but there could be some corner case I'm missing.